# find mosquitos' head in the image

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have images of mosquitos similar to these ones and I would like to automatically circle around the head of each mosquito in the images. They are obviously in different orientations and there are random number of them in different images. some error is fine. Any ideas of algorithms to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This problem resembles a face detection problem, so you could try a naïve approach first and refine it if necessary.

First you would need to recreate your training set. For this you would like to extract small images with examples of what is a mosquito head or what is not.

[image: Training set example]

Then you can use those images to train a classification algorithm, be careful to have a balanced training set, since if your data is skewed to one class it would hit the performance of the algorithm. Since images are 2D and algorithms usually just take 1D arrays as input, you will need to arrange your images to that format as well (for instance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

I normally use support vector machines, but other algorithms such as logistic regression could make the trick too. If you decide to use support vector machines I strongly recommend you to check libsvm (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), since it's a very mature library with bindings to several programming languages. Also they have a very easy to follow guide targeted to beginners (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf).

If you have enough data, you should be able to avoid tolerance to orientation. If you don't have enough data, then you could create more training rows with some samples rotated, so you would have a more representative training set.

As for the prediction what you could do is given an image, cut it using a grid where each cell has the same dimension that the ones you used on your training set. Then you pass each of this image to the classifier and mark those squares where the classifier gave you a positive output. If you really need circles then take the center of the given square and the radius would be the half of the square side size (sorry for stating the obvious).

[image]

So after you do this you might have problems with sizes (some mosquitos might appear closer to the camera than others) , since we are not trained the algorithm to be tolerant to scale. Moreover, even with all mosquitos in the same scale, we still might miss some of them just because they didn't fit in our grid perfectly. To address this, we will need to repeat this procedure (grid cut and predict) rescaling the given image to different sizes. How many sizes? well here you would have to determine that through experimentation.

This approach is sensitive to the size of the "window" that you are using, that is also something I would recommend you to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

There are some research may be useful:

- [A Multistep Approach for Shape Similarity Search in Image Databases](http://math.nist.gov/mcsd/Seminars/2009/2009-04-21-Dogan.html)
- [Representation and Detection of Shapes in Images](http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/talks/shapes.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

From the pictures you provided this seems to be an extremely hard image recognition problem, and I doubt you will get anywhere near acceptable recognition rates.

I would recommend a simpler approach:

First, if you have any control over the images, separate the mosquitoes before taking the picture, and use a white unmarked underground, perhaps even something illuminated from below. This will make separating the mosquitoes much easier.

Then threshold the image. For example here i did a quick try taking the red channel, then substracting the blue channel*5, then applying a threshold of 80:

[image]

Use morphological dilation and erosion to get rid of the small leg structures.

Identify blobs of the right size to be moquitoes by Connected Component Labeling. If a blob is large enough to be two mosquitoes, cut it out, and apply some more dilation/erosion to it.

Once you have a single blob like this

[image]

you can find the direction of the body using Principal Component Analysis. The head should be the part of the body where the cross-section is the thickest.

[image]